# Splitting a DataTable into Multiple DataTables

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable

All, I have a utility to export DataTables to Excel (into *both* .xls and .xlsx file types). When I reach a column or row limit on the `DataTable` (being pulled from SQL Server), I want to split the `DataTable` into children, each obaying the limits (for .xls 256 columns and 65,536 rows and .xlsx 16,384 columns and 1,048,576 rows).

So far, I have written the following method to do what I want

```
public static List<DataTable> SplitDataTable(DataTable mother, int nColLimit)
{
    List<int[]> rangeList = new List<int[]>();
    int primaryCols = mother.Columns.Count;
    int nSplitCount = Convert.ToInt32(primaryCols / nColLimit);
    int max = -1;

    // Get the child ranges.
    int tmpSup = 0;
    for (int splits = 0; splits < nSplitCount; splits++)
    {
        if (rangeList.Count == 0)
            tmpSup = (splits + 1) * (nColLimit - 1);
        else
            tmpSup = rangeList[splits - 1][1] + nColLimit;
        rangeList.Add(new int[2] { splits * nColLimit, tmpSup });
        if (max < tmpSup)
            max = tmpSup;
    }
    rangeList.Add(new int[2] { ++max, primaryCols });

    // Build child DataTables.
    List<DataTable> childList = new List<DataTable>();
    int childIndex = 0;
    foreach (int[] range in rangeList)
    {
        childList.Add(new DataTable());
        for (int i = range[0]; i < range[1]; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < mother.Rows.Count; j++)
                childList[childIndex].Rows[j][i] = mother.Rows[j][i];
        childIndex++;
    }
    return childList;
}
```

This however, throws an `indexOutOfRangeException` with the message "There is no row at position 0.". I appreciate where the error is coming from but what is the best way to copy the complete columns from the `mother` to a child?

I have also tried

```
List<DataTable> childList = new List<DataTable>();
int childIndex = 0;
foreach (int[] range in rangeList)
{
    childList.Add(new DataTable());
    foreach(DataRow row in mother.Rows)
    {
        DataRow tmpRow = childList[childIndex].NewRow();
        for (int i = range[0]; i < range[1]; i++)
            tmpRow[i + 1] = row[i + 1];
    }
    childIndex++;
}
```

which give the same range exception.

Thanks for your time.

*Edit: how I did this short term*

```
foreach (int[] range in rangeList)
{
    childList.Add(new DataTable());
    string strSqlTmp =
    String.Format("declare @columns varchar(max) " +
        "select  @columns = case when @columns is null " +
        "then '' " +
        "else @columns + ', ' " +
        "end + name " +
             "from sys.columns " +
             "where object_id = object_id('{0}') and name in " +
                 "(SELECT COLUMN_NAME " +
                     "FROM [{1}].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS " +
                     "WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'{0}' " +
                     "AND ORDINAL_POSITION > {2} AND ORDINAL_POSITION < {3}) " +
        "declare @query varchar(max) " +
        "set @query = 'select ' + @columns + ' from {0}' " +
        "exec (@query);
    // Then get each DataTable from SQL Server and fill the child list...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the `IndexOutOfRange` exception is because you're attempting to reference `Column`s in your new `DataTable` that don't exist.  This line:

```
childList.Add(new DataTable());
```

does indeed add a new `DataTable` to `childList`, but that `DataTable` has no columns and rows.

Normally I might use the [`DataTable.Clone()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) method to create a new `DataTable` with the same structure as the `DataTable` the method was called on, but obviously this won't work for you.  In your case you'll have to explicitly add `DataColumn`s using the [`DataTable.Columns.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumncollection.add.aspx) method.

Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++) {
    dataTable.Columns.Add(string.Format("Column {0}", i));
}
```

The snippet above is very simplistic.  Since you'll be creating the `DataColumn`s yourself you'll need to name and type each `DataColumn` yourself.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. In the mean time I skimped out and asked SQL Server to do it. I have edited my question to show how this was done if you interested...

Comment: Glad you got it working and thanks for posting your solution.

Comment: can you please look into one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688229/how-to-split-data-table-into-multiple-tables-with-adding-1-minute-delay) related to it?

Answer (score 1):

I just created a method for Splitting up a data table. The ".Batch" method is referenced from MoreLinq.

```
private static List<DataTable> SplitTable(DataTable originalTable, int batchSize)
        {
            List<DataTable> tables = new List<DataTable>();

            foreach (var rowBatch in originalTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Batch(batchSize))
            {
                var batchTable = new DataTable(originalTable.TableName);

                foreach (DataColumn column in originalTable.Columns)
                    batchTable.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.DataType);

                foreach (DataRow row in rowBatch)
                    batchTable.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);

                tables.Add(batchTable);
            }
            return tables;
        }
```

Just in case this would be helpful to anyone :)